# Function to de-link nodes and linking them to another linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list

Given the following data structure:

```
typedef struct list{
    int num1, num2, num3;
    struct list * next;
} node;
```

I have this function to delink a node in case it meets a X condition and then link it to another linked list such that I have a linked list with all the delinked nodes.

```
void delinkNodes(node * register, node ** registerDeleted) {
    node * auxNode;
    while(register->next!= NULL && register->next->next!= NULL) {
        if (helperCheckCondition(register->next)) {
            printf("De-linking node!\n");
            auxNode= register->next->next;
            *registerDeleted= register->next;
            register->next=auxNode;
        }
        else {
            register=register->next;
        }
    }
}
```

It works since after call the function, if I try to traverse the new linked list it prints out the last delinked node.

The issue is that: It's only the last delinked node. I can't seem to think of a way of linking the delinked nodes together.
Then there is the other issue of setting the last node->nextvalue to NULL.

Without writing code in an answer (for now..): What do I need to use in order to solve this in the best possible way? More aux variables...some pattern I might be forgetting...any hints?

Comment: You are just replacing the `*registerDeleted` list and not linking it in to the existing list. Need something like: `register->next->next = *registeredDeleted; *registerDeleted= register->next;`

Comment: Yes you are right. I was aware of that yet I couldn't find a way inside that loop to keep on adding nodes after starting with the first delinked one.

If I try this the program will implode as the pointer registeredDeleted is set to NULL before passing it to the function (So as soon as the condition is triggered for the first time, the original linked list will be lost as now register->next->next == NULL)

Comment: You seem to be making trouble for yourself by conceiving this as some kind of special case.  What you describe is simply to remove the node from one linked list and then add it to another.  You don't necessarily need a for-purpose function for that: generic linked-list "remove" and "add" functions could be paired to do the same, as long as they work at the node level rather than at the value level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues:

- You need to distinguish between the *first* node to add to the result list and the next ones: only the first time do you need to assign to `*registerDeleted`, as that is the *head* node of that list, but the other times you need to extend that list, which does not impact the value of `*registerDeleted`. So you need a helper variable that will point to the *tail* of that result list.
- The condition `register->next->next != NULL` suggests that the tail node could never be candidate for deletion. This is probably not what you intended.
- Don't forget to set the last `next` pointer in the result list to `NULL`.

If you cannot figure it out, here is a hidden solution:

> `void delinkNodes(node * register, node ** registerDeleted) {`
>      `if (register == NULL) return;`
>      `node * currentNode = register->next;`
>      `node * tailNode = NULL;`
>      `while (currentNode != NULL) {`
>          `if (helperCheckCondition(currentNode)) {`
>              `printf("De-linking node!\n");`
>              `​register->next = currentNode->next;`
>              `if (tailNode == NULL) { // First time only`
>                  `tailNode = *registerDeleted = currentNode;`
>             `​ } else {`
>                 `​ tailNode = tailNode->next = currentNode;`
>             `​ }`
>              `tailNode->next = NULL; // Make sure the end of the list is marked!`
>         `​ }`
>         `​ else {`
>              `​register = currentNode;`
>         `​ }`
>          `currentNode = register->next;`
>     `​ }`
>  `}`